# C++ Boost Interval and cos

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interval

I have trouble using the Interval library from Boost

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>

void test()
{
    typedef boost::numeric::interval<double> Interval;

    Interval i1(1.0, 2.0);

    auto i2 = cos(i1);
}
```

I get the following compilation errors:

```
transc.hpp(73): error C2039: 'cos_down' : is not a member of 'boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_math<double>'
transc.hpp(73): error C2039: 'cos_up' : is not a member of 'boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_math<double>'
transc.hpp(75): error C2039: 'cos_up' : is not a member of 'boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_math<double>'
```

I have tried several combinations of `interval_lib::policies` but have not been able to compile an example. I am not after very high precision. What I want is basically that adding two intervals is equivalent of adding two `double`s.

Comment: Vladimir, that does not solve it, unfortunately.

Comment: Here it is an example on how to create rounding policy for transcendental functions based on a multiprecision library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/numeric/interval/examples/transc.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interval class expects rounding and checking policies. Change your interval typedef to the following and it should compile. You'll need to read through the documentation to understand exactly what policies you need in your case.

```
typedef interval<double, policies<save_state<rounded_transc_std<double> >,
                    checking_base<double> > > Interval;
```

Comment: This compiles -- thanks. I had previously tried what you wrote, but with `rounded_arith_exact` instead. That gave the same error.

Comment: What I should have used is `rounded_transc_exact`. I see.

Comment: There are no default rounding policies for the trascendental functions, though the library does provide a number of ready made policy classes.