# boost interval arithmetic and trigonometric functions

Tags: c++, math, boost, intervals, trigonometry

I have a question which is related to the question (and answers) available over here:
[C++ Boost Interval and cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860761/c-boost-interval-and-cos/39336784#39336784)
I am also trying to use the interval arithmetic to compute trigonometric functions, and I am facing similar problems to the one presented by the Author of the question above. I tried to use the answer for the question linked above and have produced the code below. But it do not compile. Here is the code:

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp> 
using namespace boost::numeric;
using namespace interval_lib;
typedef interval<double, policies<save_state<rounded_transc_std<double> >, checking_base<double> >   > Interval;
int main()
{  
    Interval i1(1.0, 2.0);
    Interval i2 = cos(i1);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/hw_rounding.hpp:15:0,
         from /usr/include/boost/numeric/interval.hpp:18,
         from interval_test.cpp:34:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp: In instantiation of ‘T boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_arith_std<T,        Rounding>::int_down(const T&) [with T = double; Rounding =        boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounding_control<double>]’:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/arith2.hpp:40:49:   required from       ‘boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies> boost::numeric::fmod(const       boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies>&, const boost::numeric::interval<T,       Policies>&) [with T = double; Policies =         boost::numeric::interval_lib::policies<boost::numeric::interval_lib::detal ::save_state_unprotected<boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_transc_std     <double> >, boost::numeric::interval_lib::checking_base<double> >]’
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/transc.hpp:62:32:   required from     ‘boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies> boost::numeric::cos(const       boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies>&) [with T = double; Policies =       boost::numeric::interval_lib::policies<boost::numeric::interval_lib::save_    state<boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_transc_std<double> >,            boost::numeric::interval_lib::checking_base<double> >]’
interval_test.cpp:44:25:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:61: error:        ‘to_int’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by         argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
 T int_down(const T& x) { this->downward(); return to_int(x); }
                                                     ^
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:61: note:    declarations in dependent base    ‘boost::numeric::interval_lib::detail::c99_rounding_control’ are not found    by unqualified lookup
/usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:61: note: use ‘this->to_int’ instead
```

I am using boost 1.54.0 and gcc 4.8.4.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It builds fine on gcc 5.4 and boost 1.58.

Comment: Thank you Ami. I am using boost 1.54.0 and gcc 4.8.4 and this is where I have this problem

Comment: You might want to add that to the question, then. Good luck!

Comment: This has been fixed in 2014/2015: https://github.com/boostorg/interval/pull/1 this fix is available in boost 1.58, so you have to upgrade your boost version

Comment: Dear M.S! Than you very much, it works after upgrading boost. I have installed 1.61.0 and it compiles with no problem. Problem solved.

Comment: @m.s. or OP please add a (self) answer so this resolution becomes visible outside the comment. Good work +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in 2014/2015: see https://github.com/boostorg/interval/pull/1

This fix is available in boost 1.58, so you have to upgrade your boost version to at least 1.58.

Comment: Thank you once more, it works with the current version of Boost.