# C++ Boost Interval and asinh

Tags: c++, boost, boost-numeric

I have a question which is related to the question (and answers) available over here:
[C++ Boost Interval and cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860761/c-boost-interval-and-cos/39336784#39336784)

The solution presented in the linked above works for me for most trigonometrical functions including the hyperbolic once. However, if I try to use the invers of this hyperbolic once, let's take asinh() as an example I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2784: "boost::numeric::interval<T,Policies>
boost::numeric::asinh(const boost::numeric::interval<T,Policies> &)":
could not deduce template argument for "const
boost::numeric::interval<T,Policies> &" from "const double"
```

A code that produces the error is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::interval_lib;
using namespace boost::numeric;

typedef interval<double, policies<save_state<rounded_transc_std<double> >,
    checking_base<double> > > Interval;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Interval test = asinh(Interval(1, 1.1));

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the boost 1_65_1 libary. How to get the invers of the hyperbolic functions running?

Of cause one workaround would be to use the identity

```
Interval test = log(Interval(1, 1.1) + sqrt(pow(Interval(1, 1.1),2)+1.));
```

This works perfectly fine and produces correct results. However, it must be possible to use the implemented asinh-function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a MSVC-related bug, because it works for me using GCC or clang:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9c67da4bcb4f33)</kbd>** (GCC c++03)
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efd92d2b450c31c3)</kbd>** (Clang c++03)

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bn = boost::numeric;
namespace bni = bn::interval_lib;

typedef bn::interval<double, bni::policies<bni::save_state<bni::rounded_transc_std<double> >,
    bni::checking_base<double> > > Interval;

int main()
{
    Interval test = asinh(Interval(1, 1.1));
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Prints

```
[0.881374,0.950347]
```